# A Field of Polynomials of a Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, linear-transformations, polynomial-rings

> Consider a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over the field $\mathbb{F}.$ Consider a linear operator $T : V \to V$ such that no nonzero subspace of $V$ is mapped into itself by $T.$ Let $\mathbb{F}[T\,]$ denote the ring of polynomials in $T.$
>
> - Prove that the null space of any nonzero $S \in \mathbb{F}[T\,]$ is trivial.
> - Prove that $\mathbb{F}[T\,]$ is a field.
> - Prove that $[\mathbb{F}[T\,] : \mathbb{F}\,] = \dim_\mathbb{F}(V).$

We were asked the above question on a recent qualifying exam in algebra, and at the time, I thought I had a solution, but thinking about it more afterward, I realized that my attempts were incorrect. From the first part of the question, it follows that $T$ is invertible with unique inverse $T^{-1}.$ But why does this guarantee that any polynomial $f(T) = a_n T^n + \cdots + a_1 T + a_0 I$ has an inverse in $F[T]?$ For the third part of the question, I would like to establish that the minimal polynomial for $T$ is identical to the characteristic polynomial for $T,$ but I am not entirely sure if this is possible. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Let $S \in \mathbb F[T]$ be non-zero as a linear transformation. Note that $ST = TS$, since $S$ is just a polynomial in $T$. Therefore, if $Sv = 0$, then $S(Tv) = T(Sv) = 0$, so $T$ maps $\ker S$ to itself i.e. if $v \in \ker S$ then $Tv \in \ker S$. However, this can happen precisely when $\ker S = \{0\}$(as $S$ is non-zero). Hence, $S$ is invertible.

Now, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is zero in $\mathbb F[T]$. Therefore, $p_T(T) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_iT^i = 0$.

> Claim to verify yourself : the characteristic polynomial of a linear operator is irreducible if and only if it has no invariant subspaces.

Now, the minimal polynomial must be the characteristic polynomial itself, and therefore $\mathbb F[T] \cong \frac{\mathbb F[x]}{p_T(x)}$. Hence, since $p_T$ is of degree the dimension of $V$, part two and three follow.

Comment: Fantastic. I am very curious by this theorem that you have stated, and I will have to remember that for future use. On the exam, I did write that $\mathbb{F}[T] \cong \mathbb{F}[x] / p_T(x),$ but I did not justify why the minimal polynomial was irreducible -- a major oversight. Once again, thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: You are welcome! In truth, this is an amazing result. You may want to also look up the following : the minimal polynomial is the same as the characteristic polynomial if and only if all eigenspaces corresponding to the matrix are one dimensional. This is another interesting fact that will have numerous applications in linear algebra.

Answer (score 3):

An answer has already appeared. But I found this a good exercise for myself; it's possible that this answer is more elementary, being expressed in terms even I can understand.

If $p(T)x=0$ then $p(T)(Tx)=Tp(T)x=0$. So the null space of $p(T)$ is $T$-invariant, so it is either $V$, meaning $p
(T)=0$, or $\{0\}$.

So if $p(T)\ne0$ then $p(T)$ is invertible. (Detail: In general it's easy to see that if $A$ is invertible then $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $A$; for example both the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial must have non-zero constant term.) So it's a field - every non-zero element is invertible.

Now note this: If $p(T)=0$ and $\deg(p)=d<\dim(V)$ then $T$ has non-trivial invariant subspaces. Because for any $x$ the span of $x,Tx,\dots T^{d-1}x$ is invariant.

So the minimal polynomial has degree $\dim(V)$ (and equals the characteristic polynomial), hence the dimension is $\dim(V)$.

We didn't use the fact mentioned in the other answer, that there are no invariant subspaces if and only if the characteristic polynomial is irreducible. That fact interested me more than the original question:

If $W$ is an invariant subspace then looking at a basis for $V$ that includes a basis for $W$ shows that the the characteristic polynomial is not irreducible. Conversely, suppose the characteristic polynomial is $pq$. If $p(T)=0$ or $q(T)=0$ then there is an invariant subspace, as above. If not then $W=q(T)V$ is an innvariant subspace (invariant because $Tq(T)x=q(T)(Tx)$; $W\ne V$ because $p(T)W=0$ and $p(T)\ne0$; $W\ne\{0\}$ because $q(T)\ne0$.)

Comment: Well done. I appreciate that your argument uses very fundamental facts about linear algebra. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you clarify your comment about the degree of the minimal polynomial. I am writing a solution for this problem, and I am not entirely sure why the degree argument goes through. We will assume the minimal polynomial is $m_T(x) = T^k + \cdots + a_1 T + a_0 I$ for some positive integer $k < n.$ Our claim is that for any nonzero vector $\alpha,$ the vector $\beta = a_{k-1} T^{k-1} \alpha + \cdots + a_1 T \alpha + a_0 \alpha$ maps to another element in the subspace that contains $\beta.$ But I do not see this. Could you explain?

Comment: I'm not sure what comment you're  referring to. "Our claim is..." _what_ subspace? I don't recall making a claim that _looks_ like that...

Comment: Oh, right. $T\beta = a_{k-1}T^k\alpha+...$, where the omitted terms are patently in the span of $\alpha,T\alpha,\dots,T^{k-1}\alpha$. The fact that $m_T(T)=0$ says precisely that $T^k$ is in the span of $I,T,\dots T^{k-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for that helpful clarification. It is a simple fact that is easily overlooked.

Comment: Could you clarify why characteristic polynomial is not irreducible if $W$ is an invariant subspace of $V?$ I understand that we can take a basis $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_k \}$ for $W$ and extend to a basis $\{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \}$ for $V,$ but why does this guarantee that the characteristic polynomial has a nontrivial factorization?

Comment: What does the matrix for $T$ in that basis look like? You're given that $T\alpha_j$ is a linear combination of $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$ for $j=1,\dots,k$. So the matrix has zeroes where? Hence $\det(T-\lambda I$ is the product of...

Comment: Once you figure out what that matrix looks like, you need a fact that "everybody" knows: If $A$ is a square matrix and $A=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\0&D\end{bmatrix}$ where $B$ and $D$ are square, then $\det(A)=\det(B)\det(D)$. You can prove this using the definition $\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{|\sigma|}\prod_{j=1}^na_{j,\sigma(j)}$, where $|\sigma|$ is the sign of $\sigma$ ($1$ is $\sigma$ is even, $-1$ if $\sigma$ is odd).

Comment: David, this does not seem to hold. I know that $\det \begin{pmatrix} B & C \\ 0 & D \end{pmatrix} = \det(B) \det(D),$ but I do not see how your result holds.

Comment: If $A=\begin{bmatrix}B&C\\0&D\end{bmatrix}$ and you know that identity about the determinant then it follows immediately that $p_A=p_Bp_D$ (writing $p_T$ for the characteristic polynomial of $T$.)